# how to get the data from child component in stepper in react material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and using material UI.

here I use Stepper that includes different forms

```
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const handleNext = () => {
      setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

here function of handleBack and handleNext call
```

here my forms are render

```
          <Stepper
            activeStep={activeStep}
            className={classes.stepper}
            classes={{ completed: classes.complete }}
          >
            {steps.map((label) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
          <React.Fragment>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                  Thank you for your order.
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                  Your order number is #2001539. We have emailed your order
                  confirmation, and will send you an update when your order has
                  shipped.
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                <div className={classes.buttons}>
                  {activeStep !== 0 && (
                    <Button onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                      Back
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Place order" : "Next"}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        </Paper>
```

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return <SignUpForm />;
    case 1:
      return <OtpPage />;
    case 2:
      return <MapPage />;
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown step");
  }
}
```

the problem is I Want to check the form before going to the next step. I am new to react js and have no idea how to do that in my app . All I need to do is get the data from form component and call an Api before going the next page I don't have good English  please manage thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `handleNext` function add your logic for calling an API like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const handleNext = async () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("SignUpData") === true) {
    // here goes API logic
    setLoading(true);
    const apiRes = await checkStep(data); // store data either in useState or use form library
    setLoading(false);
    if(!apiRes.error){
      setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
    }
   
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks but I need to get data from that from component